# Multiple UiCollectionview Reload issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have created multiple `UICollectionView` programmatically and I have set values dynamically working fine. I want update now 3 `UICollectionView` only. How to reload it.

Below I attached my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    CGFloat x =0;
    CGFloat viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    collectionview =[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, viewWidth, 160) collectionViewLayout:layout];

    collectionview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    collectionview.tag=i;
    [collectionview setTag:i];
    [collectionview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@“Cell” bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@“Cell”];

    collectionview.delegate=self;
    collectionview.dataSource=self;

    [self.view addSubview:collectionview];
    x=x+viewWidth;        
}
```

Comment: show the relevant code please

Comment: you have created 3 collectionview programatically , you need to create global (strong) object of it.  and use reloadData() method to reload collection view

Comment: `colview1.reloadData()` , `colview2.reloadData()`, `colview3.reloadData()`, Thats it.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<4; i++)  {
        CGFloat x =0;
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        collectionview =[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 160) collectionViewLayout:layout];
        collectionview.tag=i;
        [collectionview setTag:i];
        collectionview.delegate=self;
        collectionview.dataSource=self;
        [self.view addSubview:collectionview];
        x=x+viewWidth;
            } . 
@3stud1ant3

Comment: @dahiya_boy i am creating programmticaly. check my code .

Comment: Change your for loop  i = 0 to some other value like i = 550 for not conflict tag with others  , then you can get collection view with [self.view viewWithTag:550]

Comment: UICollectionView *Collection = (UICollectionView *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
[Collection reloadData];

Comment: @VarinderSingh thank u...

Comment: @ManiVasanth Working?

Comment: @VarinderSingh ya i got idea from ur code, modified some tag value its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get collectionView using viewWithTag.

```
UICollectionView *Collection = (UICollectionView *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
```

Then, just reload the data or do whatever:

```
[Collection reloadData];
```